# iOS Simulator failed to install the application in Titanium

Tags: ios7, titanium, xcode5, ios-simulator, titanium-mobile

I have created a Titanium ios 3.1.0 app, But now when I am trying to run  it is giving me the following error.

```
[ERROR] :  An error occurred running the iOS Simulator

[ERROR] :  [DEBUG] Session could not be started: 
Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=1 
"SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: -3"
 UserInfo=0x7fe2b84837c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=SpringBoard failed to 
launch application    with error: -3, DTiPhoneSimulatorUnderlyingErrorCodeKey=-3}
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 1m 8s 528ms
```

Currently it shows only black screen

I have no idea what to do next, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do following and you would be good to go

1)Clean the project

2)Delete the build

3)And final and most important reset the simulator

Thanks