# Appcelerator error: Project failed to build after

Tags: appcelerator-mobile, ios7.1

```
    Does Anybody help me on find what this error is? I got this error while debugging for iOS.

    Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.2.1, Titanium SDK version 3.2.0.GA
    Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
    Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/
    [INFO] :   Deploy type: development
    [INFO] :   Building for target: simulator
    [INFO] :   Building using iOS SDK: 7.1
    [INFO] :   Building for iOS iPhone Simulator: 7.1
    [INFO] :   Building for device family: iphone
    [INFO] :   Minimum iOS version: 6.0
    [INFO] :   Debugging enabled via debug host: 192.168.0.4:50333
    [INFO] :   Profiler disabled
    [INFO] :   Initiating prepare phase
    [INFO] :   Initiating Xcode pre-compile phase
    [INFO] :   Processing JavaScript files
    [INFO] :   Compiling localization files
    [INFO] :   Checking for Splash Screen localization
    [INFO] :   Skipping xcodebuild
    [INFO] :   Finished building the application in 4s 559ms
    [INFO] :   Running application in iOS Simulator
    [INFO] :   Launching application in iOS Simulator
    [INFO] :   Focusing the iOS Simulator
    [ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 10s 972ms
```

On logfile I have this:

!ENTRY com.aptana.core 4 0 2014-03-17 17:29:29.765
!MESSAGE (Build 3.2.1.201402041146) [ERROR]  Error cleaning the build before launching
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error while invoking a synchronous builder
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.launching.TitaniumSingleProjectLaunchConfigurationDelegate.cleanBuild(TitaniumSingleProjectLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:79)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.ios.ui.launching.simulator.IOSSimulatorLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(IOSSimulatorLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.BuildConfiguration, int, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1641)
    at com.aptana.core.util.BuildUtil.syncBuild37(BuildUtil.java:117)
    at com.aptana.core.util.BuildUtil.syncBuild(BuildUtil.java:73)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.launching.TitaniumSingleProjectLaunchConfigurationDelegate.cleanBuild(TitaniumSingleProjectLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:75)
    ... 6 more
!SUBENTRY 1 com.aptana.core 4 0 2014-03-17 17:29:29.766
!MESSAGE Error while invoking a synchronous builder
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.BuildConfiguration, int, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1641)
    at com.aptana.core.util.BuildUtil.syncBuild37(BuildUtil.java:117)
    at com.aptana.core.util.BuildUtil.syncBuild(BuildUtil.java:73)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.launching.TitaniumSingleProjectLaunchConfigurationDelegate.cleanBuild(TitaniumSingleProjectLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:75)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.ios.ui.launching.simulator.IOSSimulatorLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(IOSSimulatorLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

Comment: I'm having exactly same problem. I tried a proposed solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22353245/339176, but it did not help. Also, building the project in Xcode works without problems.

I'm starting to suspect that this is related to recent updates of iOS SDK or XCode itself, since I have not touched Titanium project for a week or so and it used to build perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen due to multiple installations of Xcode and incorrect iOS SDK Home value set in Titanium Studio Preferences, which maybe pointing to a different location of Xcode than the current one or the needed one.

I was on Xcode 5.1 and iOS SDK 7.1 with iOS simulator version 7.1. The Titanium SDK version in my tiapp.xml is 3.3.0.GA. I had multiple installations of Xcode ranging from Xcode 4.5, 5.0, 5.0.2 and 5.1 on my Mac machine running Mac Mavericks. I was able to solve it the following way -

1. From the Titanium Studio menu options, select Preferences.
2. From the Preferences window, expand the Studio drop down and inside that expand the Platforms drop down and select iOS.
3. Under the General section on the right, check if the iOS SDK Home is set to the current version as per the Run Configuration you are building the app against. For me, it was set to Xcode 5.0.2 version when it should have been actually set to Xcode 5.1 version (I guess needed for running on iOS simulator version 7.1 with Titanium SDK version 3.3.0.GA). You can find the steps to change it by clicking on the More Details link provided in the Note below.
4. Click Apply and run the application again, better even to do a clean and run.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my project was building fine and then next minute I get this error and couldn't get rid of it.

In the end the only thing that fixed it for me was to delete the build directory from your app, then build again.